# Flume sink data not found on hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume, sink

I am able to stream data using flume and flume-sources-SNAPSHOT.jar from twitter API. The data is echoed on the terminal but does not store it in the hdfs sink. 
My flume-twitter.conf flie looks contains:

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = ****
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = ****
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = ****
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = ****

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = trump, donald trump

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/flume/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

I have assigned the 4 keys.
Please consider.
Thanks.

Comment: What does the logs say?

Comment: Thank you @franklinsijo for the reply. But i was able to solve it by granting permissions for hdfs storage and creating the directory /user/flume manually.